# Ubuntu MySQL stopped by itself and cannot start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm new to the server configurations. I have a website hosted on an ubuntu server. The website tells me that it can't connect to the database. I logged in to the server and typed `mysql` and I get the following error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I also did `sudo service mysql status` and I get the following error

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-06-10 15:46:54 CEST; 8min ago
    Process: 1400808 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1400816 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 1400816 (code=exited, status=2)
     Status: "Server is operational"

Jun 10 15:46:54 vm40565 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 10 15:46:54 vm40565 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 10 15:46:54 vm40565 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 10 15:46:54 vm40565 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:46:54 vm40565 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I tried multiple solutions from Stack Overflow but nothing works, I always get the `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` Error.

Comment: You should examine your MySQL Server error log to see if there are any lines that give a clue about why it is not starting. Look for lines annotated with "ERROR".

Comment: @BillKarwin I just did that, I see the following https://prnt.sc/-D856iDA3ntJ

Comment: @BillKarwin I just want to understand if this error is from a corupted Database or MySQL on the server is faulty. Should I reinstall MySQL from scratch. If I try to login to mysql as root `mysql -u root` I still get the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket`

Comment: You can't connect because mysqld is not running. It failed to start up. It looks like a code bug in MySQL Server. It should never encounter a signal 11 (segmentation violation). You could try starting with [innodb_force_recovery=2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) or greater value (read that manual first to understand it). The force recovery mode should be used temporarily, just to allow you to get a mysqldump of your data.

Comment: @BillKarwin I actually have a dump from today morning and another one from 13th of May. Should I anyway use innodb_force_recovery=2  ? Also could you please lead me to where I can add innodb_force_recovery=1 on my server? I use Ubuntu

Comment: @BillKarwin After changing the my.cnf file with `innodb_force_recovery=2` I get the following message `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: Any clues in the mysqld error log?

Comment: If you already have a data dump that is satisfactory, then perhaps you don't need this force-recovery business. You could just restore that data dump to a new MySQL Server instance and see if it is effective at eliminating any data corruption. It's a worthwhile test, but I suspect this is going to be a code problem with MySQL 8.0.29. It may happen again.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really not the best place to do ongoing troubleshooting like this. I keep seeing warnings about avoiding extended discussions in comments. If you continue to have problems, you should probably hire a MySQL data recovery consultant. Reach out to Percona or Pythian.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin I'll keep that in mind. Would it be safe to completly remove MySQL from my server and reinstall it and add the dumps that I have? That would be my last question to you

Comment: If you're confident in the data dump, then sure. But I tend to be conservative, so I don't want to delete files if I might need them for further testing. I would therefore prefer to create a new instance instead of deleting the old one, as long as I had enough storage space. In any case, I don't want to recommend you delete your current database and then it turns out your backup is not readable for some reason.